# Using tc for traffic quotas?

Tags: iptables, cgroups, tc, traffic

Is it possible to implement traffic quotas (absolute limits, not rate limits) based on the [network classifier cgroup](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/net_cls.txt)?

I see there is the [iptables netfilter 'quota' extension](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.13), which seems to do essentially what I am trying to do: On a given interface and direction, ALLOW traffic up to a given quota, then DROP - or do something else. However, since I only want to apply this quota to a given cgroup, I would have to use the [net_cls module](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/net_cls.txt) to identify the traffic.

I know I can set a rate limit using [Linux traffic control (tc)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) based on the classid. I could also drop traffic, if I have an appropriate classifier. What I can't seem to find is either an absolute counter for tc, or a way for iptables to filter based on classid.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with iptables based on classid. There is an example in the [net_cls module](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/net_cls.txt) link you provided.

```
echo 0x100001 >  /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/0/net_cls.classid
iptables -A OUTPUT -m cgroup ! --cgroup 0x100001 -j DROP
```

You can of course, change the example make iptables jump to another chain with more complex rules. Maybe:

```
echo 0x100001 >  /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/0/net_cls.classid
iptables -N QUOTA
iptables -A QUOTA -m quota --quota 52428800 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A QUOTA -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x100001 -j QUOTA
```

Comment: Heh, now I just wonder how I could miss this. Thanks a lot. It just looks like the cgroup extension is not actually released, so there was very little documentation found elsewhere.

Comment: So, I had to follow these instructions to build the module: http://serverfault.com/questions/560179/route-traffic-from-a-cgroup-via-a-specific-network-interface

Comment: Confirmed to work. :)